# Why is the Jacobi symbol the product of the Legendre symbols of its prime factorization?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Does someone know the proof of why the Jacobi symbol is the product of the Legendre symbols of its prime factorization? i.e. why does:

$$\left(\frac{z}{pq}\right) = \left(\frac{z}{p}\right)\left(\frac{z}{q}\right)$$

when p and q are primes (I know there is a more general one, but the one above suffices for my application. Also, leaving the full generalization as an exercise might be fun after I get some ideas how to proceed)?

I tried using the definition of the Legendre symbol:

$\left(\dfrac{z}{p}\right) = z^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \pmod p$

$\left(\dfrac{z}{p}\right) = z^{\frac{q-1}{2}} \pmod q$

$\left(\dfrac{z}{pq}\right) = z^{\frac{pq-1}{2}} \pmod {pq}$

However, I was not sure how to keep going because I realized that the Jacobi symbol is a remainder mod pq and the other two are in mod p and q, which got me stuck. However, I thought of then apply maybe the Chinese remainder theorem but it didn't seem right because the Legendre symbols for p and q were not the same. I also tried multiplying the two legendre symbols to see what I get but it doesn't seem to match at all with $\left(\frac{z}{pq}\right) = z^{\frac{pq-1}{2}} \pmod {pq}$.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula $\left(\frac{z}{p}\right) = z^{(p-1)/2}$ only holds for Legendre symbols, where $p$ is an odd prime, and $(z,p)=1$.  The definition of the Jacobi symbol is the multiplicative extension of the Legendre symbol, i.e., $$\left(\frac{z}{p_1 p_2 \ldots p_n}\right) = \left(\frac{z}{p_1}\right)\left(\frac{z}{p_2}\right)\ldots\left(\frac{z}{p_n}\right)$$  where $p_i$'s are (not necessarily distinct) odd primes, relatively prime to $z$.

An [alternative definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zolotarev%27s_lemma#Jacobi_symbol) of the Jacobi symbol is that $\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)$ is the sign of the permutation of the multiplication by $a$ map on $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

Comment: So is the Jacobi symbol, actually defined differently from the legendre symbol but use the same notation? I.e. is the following just not true: $$(\frac{z}{pq}) \neq z^{\frac{pq-1}{2}} \pmod {pq}$$?

Comment: @Pinocchio That's correct, it's defined differently but uses the same notation.

Comment: Oh, no wonder it was confusing. Well, I guess that fixes my question. The proof is that they are equal by definition?

Comment: @Pinocchio Yes.  There is also a different definition (see my edit), but most people define use the definition where it's multiplicative.